# How newsql supports to the ACID property?

Tags: database

Nosql has a distributed structure n that why it does not support to ACID property? newsql has also distributed structure so how can newsql gives guarantee that ACID is supporter

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, both NoSQL and NewSQL databases often have distributed architectures.  Being distributed does not preclude providing ACID guarantees, nor does using or not using SQL, as in fact there are some ACID NoSQL databases.  They are separate things.

However, in the early days of NoSQL, it was often argued that in order to provide the scale needed for web applications, not only was it necessary to use a distributed architecture, but also to get rid of SQL, relational tables, and ACID guarantees.  NewSQL in many ways refuted this argument, showing that databases could be distributed and scalable without giving up those things, by using a specialized architecture, often a distributed architecture.

Each database is different, and even among databases that are "ACID-compliant" there are many variations in the actual guarantees they provide, so it's often important to read the fine print.

For example, some ACID databases limit the scope of a transaction to a single operation, such as inserting or updating a single record.  Others relax the definition of isolation so that it is possible to get incorrect results.  Other relax durability, so there is a possibility that some "committed" transactions might not survive an outage.  Many database claim to be ACID-compliant, but that doesn't mean you can use them all to do things like guarantee only one person reserves a seat on a plane, or that orders never exceed inventory, or that purchases never exceed the customer's available balance.

It is possible to adhere to very strict definitions of ACID, and support complex transactions, while still being distributed and scalable.  One example is VoltDB.  VoltDB has a detailed description of how it handles transactions here: http://voltdb.com/sites/default/files/tn-transactions.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> If you are looking for pure ACID properties (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) , NoSQL may not be accurate solution.
>
> If you are looking for two attributes out of three CAP ( Consistency, Availability & Partitioning), NoSQL is right solution.

But some of the NoSQs like MongoDB can come close to implementing ACID properties ( except some compromise on durability)

Refer to below article on how MongoDB implements ACI (and not complete D) [How ACID is MongoDB](https://dzone.com/articles/how-acid-mongodb)